# Neo4jClient - Query did not return the the values in view

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I installed neo4j and neo4jClient in my MVC Project 4.0.

Install example movie database from the guide

```
:play movies
```

I made the following settings in Web.Config:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="ClientDBUrl" value="http://localhost:7474/db/data" />
<add key="ClientDBUser" value="neo4j" />
<add key="ClientDBPassword" value="password" />
</appSettings>
```

Made WbApiConfig.cs in App_Start Folder

```
public class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;

        var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);

        //Use an IoC container and register as a Singleton
        var url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientDBUrl"];
        var user = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientDBUser"];
        var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientDBPassword"];
        var client = new GraphClient(new Uri(url), user, password);
        client.Connect();

        GraphClient = client;
    }

    public static IGraphClient GraphClient { get; private set; }
}
```

Created a Model

```
 public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Then i write simple query in controller to exact the data in view

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var query = WebApiConfig.GraphClient.Cypher.Match("(p:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie {title: 'Top Gun'})")
            .Return(p => p.As<Person>()).Results;

        return View(query.ToList());
    }
```

and in view

```
@model IEnumerable<Neo4j_TestProject1.Models.Person>
<table>
  @foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @item.Name
    </td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

But i get the error of "Object Reference not Set to an Instance" in my query.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the error - but! - I think I know where it's going wrong for you.

The `Movies` data set does have a `Person` label, but if you look at it, you'll see there are only 2 properties `born` and `name`. So you're `Age` and `Id` properties will never be set, ignoring that for the moment as you aren't viewing them - the `Name` property you have will *also* not be set - and that's because Neo4j is case-sensitive.

If you change your `Person` class to:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")] // <-- Added
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

You will get names, you're basically telling `Neo4jClient` to translate for you.

You could modify your `Person` class to be like this:

```
public class Person
{
    private int _born;
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("born")]
    public int Born
    {
        get => _born;
        set
        {
            _born = value;
            Age = DateTime.Now.Date.Year - value;
        }
    }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Which would get you the age if you want it!